# Cannot load netCDF4 in a python function

Tags: python, dll, netcdf4

I freshly install python 10 on my windows machine (which has crashed a few days ago and had not this problem before). I then installed modules using pip and particularly netCDF4

```
pip install netCDF4
```

While running python in command line I can import netCDF4 without trouble but when I run my main code calling a function that import netCDF4 it throws an error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _netCDF4

I tried to remove all modules and python, reinstall only netCDF4 without success. I tried to install python 3.9 and 3.8 but no change.

To be sure I installed netCDF4 libraries on windows through the unidata web site and add the path to dll files in the environment variables. Without success.

I checked the site-packages and netCDF4 directory permission and everything seems fine. I've no problem with other modules (such as hdf5 which is similar).

Comment: have you tried to install using conda install netcdf or netcdf4?? let the machine reinstall the packages along with it. i suspect something supporting is missing

Comment: I will try this. At the moment I've never mix different installers on a machine but for you I'll give it a try

Comment: I've try once a gain a step by step install and just installed h5py: no problem. I installed then netCDF4 and h5py did not work anymore. I desinstall all libraries and then install netCDF4 before h5py, this time netCDF4.dll was not found anymore. I follow your advice and install it via anaconda, it works. I don't like the 'anaconda prompt stuff' but I'll get used to it. Thank you. Answer the question so I can mark your answer as the best one.